# Asp.Net Core UserClaimsPrincipalFactory lost claims

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am extending UserClaimsPrincipalFactory class for generting custom claims and everything works OK. The problem is that after some time, couple hours usually, all custom claims are lost. Only user name claim is available.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I had same issue. This lost about 30 minutes after login success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have override the wrong method. I should override GenerateClaimsAsync instead of CreateAsync. Now it works.

Comment: I don't want to downvote, but this solution did not work for me.